# I want to work on Wireguard project, I downloaded the project from github, but when I try to run it in Android Studio, it gives the following error

Tags: java, android, kotlin

from E:\wire\New folder\wireguard-android-master\tunnel
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (add_executable):
Cannot find source file:

```
wireguard-tools/src/wg-quick/android.c
```

Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .mpp .m .M .mm .ixx .cppm .h
.hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx .f .F .for .f77 .f90 .f95 .f03 .hip .ispc

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (add_executable):
No SOURCES given to target: libwg-quick.so

CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.

Comment: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

Comment: Have you tried building it with `make` and ndk?

Comment: Yes, I tried but it was not fixed